# Index position in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, indexing, scope, directive

I have the following directive:

```js
app.directive('showIndex', function() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, index) {
            console.log(index);
        }
    }
});
```

I apply it to an ng-repeat as such:

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in list" show-index>{{item.name}}</div>
```

assume "list" is just an array with two objects in the controller. The current directive will show this:

[image]

It just returns a giant object with all the information. All i want is the index position, i.e.:

0
1

to show up in the console

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need a directive for this, however, when using `ngRepeat`, you get access to `$index` for free. As a result, we can access it via:

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fXN9OWlKEKHMMlgzKHmI

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
  {{$index}}.) {{item.name}}
</div>
```

And we can pass this variable to our controller if necessary:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list" show-index>
   <div ng-click="logIndex($index)">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('SomeController', function($scope) {
    scope.logIndex = function(index) {
        console.log(index);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do to get the index position in the directive is to use "scope.$index".